# Triggered Send - Export errored addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

How can I export the errored Email Addresses of a Triggered Send?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no direct way to access these via the UI.

You would either need to use filters or queries on your [sendlog](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) data extension (if you activated it) or query the [_Sent Dataview](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_sent/) and compare this against your API log of submitted values.

The below is assuming you created a DE that contains all the submitted API calls to the specific trigger named API_Trigger_Log

The query would likely look something like this:

```
SELECT EmailAddress
FROM API_Trigger_Log
WHERE EmailAddress NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT SubscriberKey as EmailAddress
  FROM _Sent
  WHERE TriggeredSendCustomerKey = {{YourTriggeredSendExternalKey}}
)
```

Comment: Thanks. The Triggered Send is part of a Journey so I think the use of Send Log is the way to go here. I have enabled it yesterday and will keep an eye on it now. But it's confusing that I have the possibility to view the queued addresses but not the errored. That does'nt make sense to me.

Comment: Agreed. But there are a lot of things that don't make sense in SFMC unfortunately.